# Node JS self._callback.apply is not a function error

Tags: javascript, node.js, typescript, callback

```
import axios from 'axios';
import * as jwt from 'jsonwebtoken';
import { Action } from 'routing-controllers';
import { Connection } from 'typeorm';

import { env } from '../env';

export function authorizationChecker(connection: Connection):
    (action: Action, roles: any[]) => Promise<boolean> | boolean {

    let validationKey: any = axios.get(env.auth.jwksUri).then(response => {
        validationKey = response.data.keys[0].value;
    }).catch();

    return async function innerAuthorizationChecker(
        action: Action,
        roles: string[]
    ): Promise<boolean> {
        // here you can use request/response objects from action
        // also if decorator defines roles it needs to access the action
        // you can use them to provide granular access check
        // checker must return either boolean (true or false)
        // either promise that resolves a boolean value
        try {
            const token = (action.request.headers.token || 
               action.request.headers.authorization).replace('Bearer ', '');
            await jwt.verify(token, validationKey);
            return true;
        } catch (e) {
            return false;
        }
    };
}
```

This is my error:

```sh
error: [app] Application is crashed: TypeError: self._callback.apply is not a
function
  (node:512) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Unhandled promise rejection
             (rejection id: 1): TypeError: Cannot read property '0' of undefined
  (node:512) [DEP0018] DeprecationWarning: Unhandled promise rejections are
             deprecated. In the future, promise rejections that are not handled
             will terminate the Node.js process with a non-zero exit code.
```

I'm trying to get the validation key set from a specific URL from a service, but somehow (without calling the function) it says that the response data is undefined. On top of that, I'm having this error: self._callback.apply is not a function.

Has someone dealt with such a callback error before? I couldn't find anything on stackoverflow relating to my problem.

Comment: `response.data.keys[0]` has a "property 0", so the error implies that `keys` there is not actually defined. Also a lot of other problems here. `return async function()` does not do what you seem to think it does, and it's not really clear here what you are expecting. Needs more context as well as some basic debugging.

Comment: I know that response.data.keys[0] is not defined. but how can it be defined if the value is being called from an api?